# I receive (null) when I send a char * with sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, client, server

I am implementing a server/client arquitecture and I can send different petitions and receive it with no problem (using a struct of message) the problem becomes when I want to send a single (char *) when I print the received (char *) it prints (null)

Here it is the client:

```
    char *mensajeRecibido;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addrt, intermediario;
    socklen_t size_addrt, size_addrt1;
         void funcion_thread()
        {
            while(1)
            {
                fprintf(stdout,"THREAD SUSCRIPTOR: ESPERO A QUE LLEGUE ALGUN MENSAJE \n");
                socket_mensajes = accept(socket_suscriptor,(struct sockaddr *)&intermediario,&size_addrt1);
                fprintf(stdout,"SUSCRIPTOR: ALGUIEN SE HA CONECTADO \n");
                read(socket_mensajes,mensajeRecibido,sizeof(mensajeRecibido));
                printf("EL mensaje es: %s \n", mensajeRecibido);
            }
        }
```

Here it is the server:

```
int publicar(char *tema, char *mensaje)
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int socketSuscriptor;
  for(i =0; i<numeroTemas;i++)
  {
    if(strcmp(map_temas[i].tema,tema) == 0)
    {
      printf("EL NUERO DE SUSCRIPTORES AL TEMA 1 ES: %d \n",map_temas[i].numeroSuscriptores);
      for(j=0;j<map_temas[i].numeroSuscriptores;j++)
      {
        socketSuscriptor = conectarConSuscriptor(map_temas[i].suscriptores[j].address_suscriptor,map_temas[i].suscriptores[j].puerto);
        if(socketSuscriptor == -1)
        {
          return -1;
        }
        write(socketSuscriptor, mensaje,strlen(mensaje)); //Envia el mensaje a los suscriptores
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int conectarConSuscriptor(struct sockaddr_in direccion_suscriptor,int puerto)
{
  struct sockaddr_in direccion_suscriptor1;
  int socketSuscriptor;
  socketSuscriptor = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

  bzero((char*)&direccion_suscriptor1,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  direccion_suscriptor1.sin_family=AF_INET;
  direccion_suscriptor1.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(inet_ntoa(direccion_suscriptor.sin_addr));
  direccion_suscriptor1.sin_port=/*htonl(*/puerto/*)*/;
  printf("La direccion del suscriptor es %s \n", inet_ntoa(direccion_suscriptor.sin_addr));
  if(socketSuscriptor<0)
  {
    printf("INTERMEDIARIO: Error al crear el socket para comunicar con el cliente \n");
  }
  if(connect(socketSuscriptor, (struct sockaddr*)&direccion_suscriptor1, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) <0)
  {
    printf("Error al conectar con el suscriptor\n");
    printf("El error es: %s",strerror(errno));
    close(socketSuscriptor);
    return -1;
  }
  return socketSuscriptor;
}
```

Comment: you didn't allocate any memory to read the string into, did you?

Comment: Have you tried checking your return values?

Comment: Im sorry I don't understand your question, when I call the function "publicar" in the server I put a mensaje and if I do a printf("%s \n,mensaje) I got the message I pass as a parameter. In the client I want to save the string message in the variable mensajeRecibido

Comment: Yes @inetknght I dont get any -1 and I already did a printf of all my values getting the correct ones except in mensajeRecibido in the client.

Comment: @BrankVictoria do you know what `char *mensajeRecibido;` does?

Comment: Yes @immibis, it is a pointer to char

Comment: @BrankVictoria Okay. Do you know what `read(socket_mensajes,mensajeRecibido,sizeof(mensajeRecibido));` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems.

```
char *mensajeRecibido;
```

This is never allocated, and using `sizeof mensajeRecibido` will only yield 4, which is almost certainly not what you want. There's no real reason to use a `char *` here. Use an array:

```
char mensajeRecibido[MESSAGE_SIZE]; // where MESSAGE_SIZE is some constant

read(socket_mensajes,mensajeRecibido,sizeof(mensajeRecibido));
printf("EL mensaje es: %s \n", mensajeRecibido);
```

You can't assume the read succeeded; you can't assume you didn't get end of stream; and you can't assume the read filled the buffer. That should be:

```
int count = read(socket_mensajes,mensajeRecibido,sizeof(mensajeRecibido));
if (rc > 0)
    printf("EL mensaje es: %.*s \n", count, mensajeRecibido);
else if (rc == 0)
    ; // peer disconnected
else  // rc < 0 -> error
    perror("recv");
```